# yii2 Create new folder and add file to it

Tags: php, yii2

I'm creating Yii2 application that allows users to download tutorial and it's subtitle. Currently I can do it separately but, what I want to do is to create a new folder with the video name and include both video and subtitle file in that folder and then create a zip and give that to the user for download. but I have no idea how to do it. I can zip the files using php  ZipArchive but i have no idea how to create new folder and include those two files in to it.

my download action is

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    // get all videos relevan for this video id 
    $video = TempVideo::findOne($id);
    $file = $video->path;

        if (file_exists($file)) 
        {
              Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
        } 
}
```

helps are highly appreciated.

Comment: So you are looking for a way to make a folder and save 2 files in it?

Comment: yep that's the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ZipArchive
http://php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

or launch command line with:

```
system('zip filecompress.zip file1 file2 file3');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the information but i think it need to mlook something like this:
you need to make a new directory with `mkdir()` (doc: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php);
and copy the needed files with `copy()` 
(doc:http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php)

```
public function actionDownload($id)
{
    // get all videos relevan for this video id 
    $video = TempVideo::findOne($id);
    $file = $video->path;

        if (file_exists($file)) 
        {
              Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file);
              $new_video_path = '/path/to/save/dir';
              //create a new dir
              mkdir($new_video_path); 
              //copy the file to a new path
              copy($file,$new_video_path.'newfilename.mp4');
              copy('subtitle/pathe.txt',$new_video_path.'subtitle.txt');

        } 
}
```

and after that you can create a zip file with the `ZipArchive` that doc can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.ziparchive.php